# How to align headerText in center?

Tags: sapui5

From the below snippet , how to align headerText "Input" at center?

```
<List
        headerText="Input">
        <InputListItem label="Price (EUR)">
            <Input
                placeholder="Price"
                value="799"
                type="Number" />
        </InputListItem>
</List>
```

However, I tried textAlign="Center" but this doesnot make any change.

But when I inspect the element and add align="center"(just to test) obiviously it does change, so how to achieve the same here in snippet?

sorry for this noob question, searched a lot but could not find any solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add html namespace in mvc:View like `<mvc:View  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
2. add css class to your view like `<html:style>.test > header { text-align:center; }</html:style>`. Test is your class you define and you will add in step 3, while > header is your child node selector (your headerText="Input" creates a header node)
3. add the class test to your List like `< List class="test" headerText="Input">...</List>`

Comment: thank you so much, the same can be achieved with styles added in .css file ?

Comment: yes, but you need to load them (like in normal HTML website) in the index.html. Then you can access the classes etc. in your xml view.

Comment: yes , i have loaded them and I should add like .test{text-align:center;} or any?

Comment: You have an external css file which will be loaded with the <link> html tag. then you just add the class to your list like described in my answer in step 3. The name of the class needs to be match the name of the class in your css file